# How Can I return both number of ints less than or equal to average and number of ints greater than average

Tags: c++

I am new to functions. I don't know how can I output numbers of ints less than or equal to average and number of ints greater than average. How I need to call my function so that it output both results ?

```
int compareAverage(int numbers[], int count, double average)
{
    int lessEqualCount = 0;
    int greaterCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++)
       {
           if (numbers[i] <= average){
               lessEqualCount++;
               return lessEqualCount;}


           else{
              greaterCount++;
              return greaterCount;}
       }
```

Comment: Why should you even check for the second case? You return `n` and the rest is `count - n` i.e. `lessEqualCount = count - greaterCount`. You don't need two return values.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions.
The first ones that come to my mind:

- accept to pointers to `int` in which to write the results
- return a `std::pair` of `int`s instead of a single value
- return a `struct` having two properties for the two values
- return an array (either a naked one or a `std::array`) containing the two values
- ...

It follows an example:

```
std::pair<int, int> compareAverage(int numbers[], int count, double average) {
    std::pair<int, int> ret = std::make_pair<int, int>(0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
        if (numbers[i] <= average) {
            ret.first++;
        } else {
            ret.second++;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```